# Date between said dates in sql server with null

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, between

I have lets say 4 records in the Pay table. Like this

```
   UserID   Pay    startdate     enddate

      44      10     2006-12-03   2007-12-31            
      44      11     2008-01-01   2008-11-01
      44      12     2008-11-02   2012-02-05 
      44      13     2012-02-05    NULL
```

User 44 is paid 10,11,12,13$ per hour in the years mentioned. My question is if now I give a date lets say 02/27/2010, then it should bring 12$ as his pay. Basically check the date between start and end and give. But now if user gives a date like 02/27/2013 then it should give 13$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if only the `enddate` field is nullable, you can do a query like

```
select UserId, Pay
from Pay
where @date between startdate and isnull(enddate, '9999-12-31')
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `where` statement:

```
select pt.pay
from PayTable pt
where '2010-02-27' >= startdate and
      ('2010-02-27' <= enddate or enddate is null);
```

Comment: @Carth . . . yes, that was a typo.